# Can't use `request.on` event handlers to close stream request on NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, stream, event-handling

I am creating an API endpoint that streams data so I can live update components based on database events.
I almost managed to make everything work, except for the clean up. After I send the request, the endpoint should stream data continuously until the connection is closed. The problem is that it keeps running the streaming logic, and I could not use `request.on` events to stop it.

Here is a mocking endpoint I've made to showcase it:

```
// pages/api/example.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    console.log('requested')
    // headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream;charset=utf-8')
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-transform')
    res.setHeader('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no')

    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('ping')
      res.write('ping on res')
    }, 2000);

    let handleExit = () => {
      console.log('this will never run',)
      res.end()
    }

    req.on('close', () => {
      console.log('Close event triggered');
      handleExit();
    });
    req.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('Finish event triggered');
      handleExit();
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      console.log('End event triggered');
      handleExit();
    });
    req.on('error', () => {
      console.log('Error event triggered');
      handleExit();
    });
    req.addListener('end', () => {
      console.log('End event triggered');
      handleExit();
    });
    req.on('readable', () => {
      console.log('Readable event triggered');
      handleExit();
    });
    console.log('all listeners set')
  }
}

export default handler
```

Now, when I `curl -N  localhost:3000/api/example` I can see `ping on res` being written on my terminal every 2 seconds, and the NextJS console output looks like:

```
wait  - compiling /api/example (client and server)...
info  - Using external babel configuration from /home/node/src/.babelrc
event - compiled successfully in 1048 ms (96 modules)
requested
all listeners set
API resolved without sending a response for /api/example, this may result in stalled requests.
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
```

...the thing is: even after I close the request (Ctrl+C), it keeps logging "ping". As shown by the output, none of the events 'close', 'finish', 'end' etc. ran.

So, my question is: why doesn't it work and how can I perform a clean up?

Comment: did you try `req.connection.on('close', () => {})` ?

Comment: have you been able to figure something out? I have the same issue. I have some long-running work triggered in the controller and I want to cancel it when request is cancelled

Comment: it seems like res.on("close") works. I have no idea why the others don't work though. And you have to store setInterval on a variable and call clearInterval(interval) on handleExit to close the interval

Answer (score 0):

The long-running connection is created by your response, not by the request. Hence the connection closed event will be triggered on your response object.

Something like this should work.

```
res.on("close", function () {
    console.log('End event triggered');
    handleExit();
});
```

It means that your code should be like this.

```
// store the interval variable so you can close interval later
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('ping')
  res.write('ping on res')
}, 2000);

// when your long-running respnose ends, clear the interval
res.on("close", function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

**Note**. The `close` event listener gets triggered only after you attempt to write to the stream with `res.write`.